Filmora Wondershare, how to change the duration of the image in the timeline
Filmora Wondershare, how do I change the duration of the image on the timeline?
Hello friends, I need help from someone who has already used this program, FILMORA, or understands how to change its settings.
When you add images to edit, and want to make a slide, the program automatically leaves each image on the timeline for 5 seconds.
I would like to change this to 3 seconds, but I can't find where to change this.
You can only change it if you click on each image and do it manually.
See the image:

I have version 8.7.0 of the program, and I know that in higher versions it is possible to make this change through the program, but I don't want to change it to higher versions, which I consider horrible and full of inutei things that only make the program confusing.
If anyone can help me, I would appreciate it.
I tried looking in the installation folder, C:\Program Files\Wondershare\Filmora
For any files that I could change, but I couldn't find them.
